# Duda con variables y recursión

Tags: prolog

en este código:

```
p(Y):- q(Y), p(Y).
q(0).
q(1).
p(1).
```

si haces `?- p(X).` da error. ¿El error es porque en lugar de Y pongo X? ¿O porque estoy intentado hacer una especie de recursión?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque como seguramente te lo dice tu error, las variables no están lo suficientemente instanciadas.

> p(Y):- q(Y), p(Y).

¿La variable `Y` que es? Para darle un rango de valores posibles podemos usar `between/3`

```
p(Y) :- 
  number(Y),
  between(0,1,Y),
  q(Y),
  p(Y).
```

Adicionalmente se observa si un pequeño problema de la definición recursiva, como no hay reglas antes, la regla con mayor precedencia es ella misma y no pasará a ninguna otra que pongas, así que dentro de sí misma intentará resolverse sin tomar en cuenta a las otras que pusiste después hasta que agote todas sus posibilidades, (y no lo intentará siquiera si falla).

Pero con este pequeño cambo que le hicimos revisemos con el compilador de prolog de mi mente (sí, me da flojera abrir el swi prolog) como se asignarían los valores:

```
p(_G1234) :- 
      number(_G1234),
      between(0,1,_G1234),
      q(_G1234),
      p(_G1234).
```

`_G1234`, porque en el compilador de mi mente el guión bajo como prefijo indica una dirección de memoria, y el 1234 es la dirección de memoria donde gugardo esa variable.

Between nos da solamente dos chances, el valor 0, el valor 1 o hace que falle, así que si lo corremos por primera vez le asignará a nuestra variable el uno.

```
p(_G1234) :- 
      _G1234 =0,
      number(_G1234), % cierto, así que se va en la siguiente
      q(_G1234), % no existe q, pero ya podemos imprimir en el debug q(0)
      p(_G1234). % intento con el mismo valor

p(_G1234) :- 
      _G1234 =0,
      p(_G1234),
      q(0). % el valor de q(0) es ignorado así que es como si no estuviera
```

Ahora que ya verificó que todo esté bien, en la consola simplemente nos dirá

> Y = 0
>
> true.

siguiente intento r o ;

```
p(_G1234) :- 
      _G1234 =1,
      p(_G1234),
      q(1). % el valor de q(1) es ignorado así que es como si no estuviera
```

Otra vez pudo saber cuanto vaía todo y todo concuerda así que vuelve a imprimir

> Y = 1
>
> true

Si le pides otro valor te dirá

> false

Así que toca volverlo a mejorar un poco, y cambiando el orden de lo que escribimos le cambiamos el sentido.

```
% parecen reglas pero son hechos, así que esto funciona como una terminación temprana
q(0).
q(1).
p(1).

p(Y):- q(Y), p(Y).
```

Ahora, a pesar de que no le dijimos explícitamente que rango de valores tiene `Y`, tiene una base de datos de hechos antes con tres reglas, como solo hay una de `p`, la intentará.

Esto solo pasará en compiladores demasiado buenos, afortunadamente el de mi mente lo es :3

```
p(1):- q(1), p(1).
```

> true

En la mayoría de compiladors tal vez necesites modificar esta regla a

```
p(Y):- number(Y),q(Y), p(Y).
```

o incluso usar un `between/3` adicional

La regla `q(0)`, como podrás ver es trivial, irrelevante, es más ya quítala, sirve para dos cosas en tu programa: para nada y para lo mismo.

Espero que con esto te quede claro como funciona tu programa y como afecta o no el uso de reglas recursivas. Como bono extra por leer hasta acá te dejo otra forma de poner tu recursividad:

```
p(Y) :- 
  number(Y),
  between(0,100,Y),
  q(Y). % simple q va a tomar valores de 0 a 100

p(Y) :- 
  number(Y),
  between(0,100,Y),
  p(Y-1). % vuelve a llamarse a si mismo con un valor menos, pero como le orden importa, toma primero la regla de arriba
```

Ahora si obtienes todas las posibles respuestas con duplicados por supuesto mediante

```
todas(TodasLasCombinaciones):-findall(Iterador, p(Iterador), TodasLasCombinaciones).
```

Obtendrás algo como:

> TodasLasCombinaciones = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...100, 99,98,97....1  ]

porque primero usará la primera regla, y después usará la segunda regla que usará a su vez la primera.